# Omit os_subnet's variable dns_nameservers in Ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I would like to omit the dns_nameservers variable from the following Openstack function if the value does not appear in the variable file:

```
 os_subnet: 
     cloud: "{{ item.cloud }}" 
     state: present
     validate_certs: no
     no_gateway_ip: yes
     dns_nameservers: 
     - "{{ item.dns | default(None) }}"
     enable_dhcp: yes
     name: "{{ item.subnet }}"
     network_name: "{{ item.network }}"
     cidr: "{{ item.cidr }}"
     allocation_pool_start: "{{ item.allocation_pool_start }}"
     allocation_pool_end: "{{ item.allocation_pool_end }}"
     host_routes: "{{ item.host_routes | default(omit) }}" 
  with_items: 
  - "{{ subnets }}"
  tags: subnets
```

Until now, I have tried to omit it with `| default(omit)` and `| default(None)`, but it is not working. Is any filter that might help or any other way?

EDIT:

Variable file:

```
- cloud: tenant1
  network: nw
  subnet: nw_subnet
  cidr: 172.12.17.64/26
  dns:
  - 8.8.8.8
  - 8.8.8.9
  allocation_pool_start: 172.12.17.68
  allocation_pool_end: 172.12.17.70
  host_routes:
  - destination: 0.0.0.0/0
    nexthop: 172.12.17.65
```

I am getting the following error:

> Reason: '[u'8.8.8.8', u'8.8.8.9']' is not a valid
>   nameserver. '[u'8.8.8.8', u'8.8.8.9']' is not a valid
>   IP address.\", \"type\": \"HTTPBadRequest\", \"detail\": \"\"}}"}

Answer (score 0):

You want to either pass a list with a single element or pass an `omit` keyword (placeholder object), which tells Ansible not to pass the whole parameter (`dns_nameservers` here) to the module:

```
 dns_nameservers: "{{ [item.dns] if item.dns is defined else omit }}"
```

---

In your example, if `item.dns` was undefined, you passed a list with a single element being an `omit` placeholder. In such case the `dns_nameservers` parameter is defined (that list which is hardcoded in the code) and behaviour is undefined (likely depends on module).

Comment: Thank you for the explanations. It really works if I have none or one elements in the dns_nameservers, but if I have more than 1, how shall I proceed? In the variable file, I have defined the dns as: `dns: - 8.8.8.8` \n `- 8.8.8.9`, but it didn't worked this way

Comment: I have tried to way, but I am getting an error. I have updated my question with the variable file that I am trying and the error. The code was changed as you suggested.

Comment: I have modified the syntax to accept more than one value; after accepting it, I will declare the answer valid